# Electric field due to rotating charged sphere

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics

Consider a spherically symmetric charged object (charge $Q$) **rotating** about its axis.

From Gauss's law we know that all that matters for the electric field $\mathbf{E}$ is the charge $Q$ enclosed ($\oint \mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{S} = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0} $). But this is in *classical* electrodynamics.

In QED, does the **rotation** cause any variation to the resulting electric field?
Maybe affecting the virtual particles whizzing around the edge of the sphere?

EDIT: The underlying reason for asking this is the following: in Newtonian gravity a spinning object of mass $M$ still generates the same gravitation field, whereas in Einstein's general relativity the additional rotational kinetic energy adds to the Stress-Energy tensor, modifying the spacetime curvature.

I was wondering if there's any deviation from the classical theory (here classical electrodynamics) when dealing with rotating sources, analogously to GR.

Comment: In QED, there's no electric field in the classical sense.

Comment: OK, a bunch of photons? Still, does rotation affect them?

Comment: No. There's not even a "bunch of photons" - quantum field theories aren't amenable to be interpreted in these notions. The most you could say is that the theory is still invariant under rotations.